# Fixing PLTE PNG With Bad Header & No IEND

Tags: image, header, hex, png

So I have a PNG file that I extracted from a base64 encoded file, I decoded it and got the following image header (no IDAT chunk and possibly invalid PLTE chunk):

[image]

and the ending has no IEND chunk, as seen here:

[image]

The Original file is here - notice the hash at the end when viewed in a hex editor:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=92484151555054173895

The decoded file (taken ONLY from the base64 data from the original file): http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01383717875609361014

I used the following tools to help identify and possibly solve issues:

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html - not so helpful

http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/ - quite helpful

I keep reading and learning more about PNG data chunks but I can't seem to make sense of it. I would really like to code a tool once I figure this out.

Comment: The IDAT chunk is the one that contains the literal image data. If you are looking for some way to retrieve the image anyway: no chance.

Comment: But all of the pixel data is there, if you look at the decoded file. It's just missing the actual IDAT byte section.

Comment: **Anyone wanna take a whack at it? I will name you as co-author of the tool** :'(

Comment: I figured it out, there is a special type of Base64 decoder/encoder that is specifically used in files as opposed to raw text.